# Fill column in DataTable with output from SQL query

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataTable with this structure:

```
number   amount    destroyed    together
     1       19            3          22
     2       20            3          23
     3       11            0          11
```

The value in the `destroyed` column is manually inserted by the user. However, I've created a table in SQL where a user can add a value for `destroyed` and I want to take the value from this table. I already have the proper SQL query for this.

The following example will demonstrate.

Here is output from the query :

```
number    destroyed     type
     1            3   papper
     2            1   papper
```

According to the structure of the DataTable it should insert a value for `destroyed` from this SQL query into DataTable when

```
Query.number = DataTable.Number
```

So according to this example it should look like:

```
number   amount    destroyed    together
     1       19            3          22
     2       20            1          21
     3       11            0          11
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried something that failed or are you asking for an ADO.NET tutorial on how to use DataTables ?

Comment: I did something like this : I set this SQL query output as a DataTable2 and then was finding numbers in DataTable2 and copy from DataTable.destroyed to DataTable.destroyed when DataTable2.number = DataTable.number but I don't think it's a good patent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted how you're connecting and executing your SQL statement. Using `SqlConnection` and friends to execute a statement:

```
// For each row in the DataTable...
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
    // Get record where number equals the DataTable's "number" column for this row
    // Then select the destroyed value:
    string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE number='{0}' THEN destroyed", dataTable.Rows[i]["number"].ToString());
    int destroyedCount = 0;

    // Execute the SQL query, return value to `destroyedCount`
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        try 
        {
            conn.Open();
            destroyedCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Set the table value to the SQL command's returned value
    dataTable.Rows[i]["destroyed"] = destroyedCount;

    // Assuming you want amount + destroyed = together
    int amountCount = 0;

    // Parse the table's current value for `amount`
    try 
    {
        amountCount = (int)dataTable.Rows[i]["amount"];
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException argEx)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }
    catch (FormatException formatEx)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }

    // Set the `together` column to `amount` + `destroyed`
    dataTable.Rows[i]["together"] = (amountCount + destroyedCount).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Parsing to INT isn't working. Im using SqlConnection.

Comment: What exception are you getting, and could you try to parse it to a string (`Console.WriteLine((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());`) to see what value the SQL command gives?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. Just have already problem while writing. The error is Cannot convert from object to string

Comment: @JustSomeNewbie Which line sorry, `destroyedCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` or `amountCount = Int32.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i]["amount"]);`?

Comment: Add this line there instead, and tell me what it outputs to the console: `Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Rows[i]["amount"]);` and this line too actually: `Console.WriteLine((int)dataTable.Rows[i]["amount"]);`

Comment: First one give me an error, but the second one is correct and it working :).